# Is this LL(1) Parser breaking due to totally wrong follows?

Tags: java, parsing, recursion, grammar

This is the grammar:

```
<program> ::= { <statement_list> }
<statement_list> ::= <statement> <statement_list’>
<statement_list’> ::= ; <statement_list’’>
<statement_list’’> ::= <statement_list> | ϵ
<statement> ::= call : <procedure_call> | compute : <expression>
<procedure_call> ::= id ( <parameters> )
<parameters> ::= <factor> <parameters’>
<parameters’> ::= , <parameters> | ϵ
<expression> ::= id = <factor><expression’>
<expression’> ::= + <factor> | - <factor> | ϵ
<factor> ::= id | num
```

I first calculated the follows wrong, these are the calculated follows on epsilons:

```
FOLLOW(<statement_list’’>) = FOLLOW(<statement_list’>) = FOLLOW(<statement_list>) ={$}
FOLLOW(<parameters’>) = FOLLOW(<parameters>) = {(}
FOLLOW(<expression’>) = FOLLOW(<expression>) = {$}
EDIT: I now see my follows are wrong.
FOLLOW(<statement_list’’>) = FOLLOW(<statement_list’>) = FOLLOW(<statement_list>) ={}}
FOLLOW(<parameters’>) = FOLLOW(<parameters>) = {)}
FOLLOW(<expression’>) = FOLLOW(<expression>) = {}}
```

This is the outputted log result:

```
{
compute
:
id
=
num
;
ERROR
ERROR
```

It's processing the semicolon as the error I believe. The source is a text file identical to the first 7 tokens, the next 6 are just "compute : id = num ;".

Comment: What grammar? What input?

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to include the "source" you're parsing. And if possible also please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: As a tip for helping debugging such issues: Begin *simple*. Don't try to make it all in one go, but instead write a small part, build and debug. When everything works then you continue to implement the next little thing., and so on. If you get a problem, you can focus on the last little piece of code added. For a parser add one rule at a time, testing it out before adding the next rule.

Comment: Yeah i realize that now. My grammar wasn't even correct, i just assumed it was and gave all the info to check against. I have edited the post.